# How to suspend or delay tiles unloading with leaflet?

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, zooming

I am using Leaflet in my api and I try to delay the tiles unloading. I feel that leaflet is somethings to strict when it comes to unloading tiles while zooming out or zooming in.
This causes unattractive zoom effects. To fix this i try to wait for unloading tiles until every new tile of current zoomlevel is loaded.

I found interesting events like the "tileunload" and "load" event.

```
pyramidTileLayer.on("tileunload",function(event) { 
            //console.log("tileunload called") 
            console.log('tileunload event for ', event);
          });

pyramidTileLayer.on("load",function() { console.log("all visible tiles have been loaded") });
```

Is it possible to utilize these events or use different techniques to achieve this behavior? Thank you very much for help in advance!

Comment: If i enable throttling on http://leafletjs.com/ i don't see the flickering you describe. (the image is blured when zoomed in and then after 10 sec when the image is loaded, it is sharp.)

Comment: I can see it even without throttling. Maybe it is browser specific. I use the latest chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: I can only see it when zooming to new tiles. like zooming out will result in grey borders around. or going right/left will result in those also. but zooming in (one scroll step each time) is fine.

Comment: But i have to agree zooming 2 steps at a time is not nice.

Comment: Yes you are right when u zooming in slowly with a scroll step one by one. But if you want to zoom in really fast you will see the issue if it is not browser specific.

Comment: Mh could you try increasing [zoomAnimationThreshold](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-zoomanimationthreshold) (for zooming) and [keepBuffer](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#gridlayer-keepbuffer) (for panning)? (pls report back i wanna know too :D)

Comment: ok thanks for the hint :)

Comment: there is a issue now on github for that https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5937#issuecomment-347060642

Comment: So looks like in new versions zooming in works well :)